# No errors but NSLog not outputting

Tags: objective-c, nslog

I am busy doing a test program in Xcode. So far I have this code in main.m. I get no errors at all, but the output isnt happening i.e NSLog in the print method.

What could be the problem? I know I must be missing something obvious.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "JTAppDelegate.h"


@interface Fraction: NSObject

-(void) print;
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void) setDenominator: (int) d;

@end

@implementation Fraction

{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}

-(void) print
{
      NSLog (@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
}

-(void) setNumerator:(int)n
{
    numerator = n;
}

-(void) setDenominator:(int)d
{
    denominator = d;
}

@end

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([JTAppDelegate class]));


        // Create an instance of Fraction and initialise it

        Fraction *myFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];

        //Set Fraction to 1/3

        [myFraction setNumerator: 1];
        [myFraction setDenominator: 3];

        //Display the fraction using the print method

        [myFraction print];
    }


}
```

Comment: hmm...control is returned from return UIApplicationMa

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279551/nslog-stopped-working-in-xcode) related question

Comment: Where do you call `print`?

Comment: He calls `print` after the the `return` statement so it is never reached.

Comment: I found the problem, the return should be at the end of the program code. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I guess there is an institute where ios training is given and all are given same task. I see similar code once in a week since past 3-4 months.!!!

Answer (score 4):

your `print`is after a `return`, this code is never reached.

Answer (score 2):

Write Print and all code above return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this :-

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {



        // Create an instance of Fraction and initialise it

        Fraction *myFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];

        //Set Fraction to 1/3

        [myFraction setNumerator: 1];
        [myFraction setDenominator: 3];

        //Display the fraction using the print method

        [myFraction print];

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([JTAppDelegate class]));

    }


}
```